# How long custom variables take to appear in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to test custom variables in analytics, but I am not sure if they appear as I track them. I have tracked successfully two other variables but I am having problem with the third, the only difference I see is the name that contains spaces `Signed up users`.

Anyway what I want to know is how many time do I have to wait to see custom variable appear?

I am using this code:

```
x=function(){_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'Signed up users', 'true', 3]);_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);}
```

And when I run this function real time result mark a visit, anyway I don't see the custom variable tracked, going to try with other variables.

Answer (score 0):

One way to test this would be to set a filter based on custom vars - since the real time view, as it says in the GA interface, "now obeys the profile filters" you should be able to deduce immediately from the real time results if your custom vars are set or not (use a test profile for this since the filter will alter your data permanently).

How long the data takes to show up in the standard reports depends on your site (the more data Google needs to compute the longer it takes) - I think in the help forum it said somewhere 4 hours, in my experience it's usually a little quicker (one to two hours).

Comment: You can't set filters based in Custom Vars.